# "restClient is not defined" although it actually is

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify

here's a snippet of my code

```
  console.log("IS RESTCLIENT UNDEFINED?");
  console.log(restClient === undefined);
  console.log(restClient);

  restClient.get(options, function(resterr, restreq, restres, restobj) {
    assert.ifError(resterr);
    //not important
    return next();
  });
```

The problem is that when it gets executed (it's basically most of the handler for a route, simple stuff, nothing esoteric) the output is as following:

```
IS RESTCLIENT UNDEFINED?
false
JsonClient {<a lot of stuff describing the client>}

assert.js:327
assert.ifError = function(err) { if (err) throw err; };
                                      ^
InternalError: restClient is not defined
at parseResponse (/srv/oms-profiles-module/node_modules/restify/lib/clients/json_client.js:67:23)
at IncomingMessage.done (/srv/oms-profiles-module/node_modules/restify/lib/clients/string_client.js:151:17)
at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:260:16)
at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:893:12)
at doNTCallback2 (node.js:430:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:344:17)
```

The client is defined at the beginning of the file "as usual" (worked until now), and it uses the npm module restify. I don't even understand if the problem could be the scoping or what else, has anybody gotten any good advice on where I could bang my head on?

Thanks

UPDATE: this is not a problem with scopes and such, I presume; I suspect it is something with restify because otherwise the error would be something like "ReferenceError: restClient is not defined". Still, I am at a loss since it was working before and I did not introduce any major change for it to break. Restify version is 3.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, the answer is simple and I feel stupid (as I should),

the assert was being fired as there is a `resterr`. It comes from the API handler that is being called with `restClient.get()`

However I was expecting the whole (other) program to do something like crash (on another assert) or to tell me `ReferenceError: restClient is not defined`, but analysing the logs it did NOT happen. Thus I thought that the problem was in the snippet up here and not in the remote API that I was calling (still coded by me).

Comment: No need to feel stupid. We've all been there. Thank you for following up.